# Usage of ToDate Function

Tags: apache-pig, to-date

I wanted to convert `userinput:chararray` to date, so I am planning to use the `ToDate(userinput,'dd/MM/yyyy')` function. I have searched the forum to see if people have used it but I am not sure if I need to register anything like piggybank.jar to use this function. My pig version is 0.14.

Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ref : http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/func.html#to-date

Its an inbuilt function, you need not register any jar. There are 4 overloaded ToDate() functions

1. ToDate(milliseconds)
2. ToDate(iosstring)
3. ToDate(userstring, format)
4. ToDate(userstring, format, timezone)

For your usecase #3 or #4 would help.

Comment: Thank you. I was travelling on the plane and researching so could not test it. Planning to use #3. Thank you for confirming.